# Getting Magento Paging to show Below Products

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I am building a site using Magento 1.7.2. On my products page I am trying to get the paging at the top of the products to also show below. I have looked at the toolbar.phtml file, catalog.xml file and even the pager.phtml file. I see where everything is kind of. But I can't seem to figure out how to add it below the products to.

You can find my site here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/genlume-collection/sld-series.html

Notice the Paging right above the products to browse product pages and view syle either list or grid. I want to show all of this below products to.

Here is my Catalog xml file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>

        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="right">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
                <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>
                <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
            </block>-->
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
                <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
            </block>-->
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
    </default>


<!--
Category default layout
-->

    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>

                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

<!--
Category layered navigation layout
-->

    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

<!--
Compare products page
-->

    <catalog_product_compare_index translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_compare_index>

    <customer_account_index>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_index>

<!--
Product view
-->

    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>

                <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>

                <block type="cms/block" name="custom_tab">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>custom_tab</block_id></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                    <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                    </block>
                    <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <!--<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
                    <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                            <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                            <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>-->
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

<!--
Additional block dependant on product type
-->
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Virtual)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_virtual" name="product.info.virtual" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.virtual.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>



<!--
Product send to friend
-->

    <catalog_product_send translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Email to a Friend</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_send" name="product.send" template="catalog/product/send.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_send>

<!--
Product additional images gallery popup
-->

    <catalog_product_gallery translate="label"> 
        <label>Catalog Product Image Gallery Popup</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_gallery" name="catalog_product_gallery" template="catalog/product/gallery.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_gallery>

<!--
SEO Site Map
-->

    <catalog_seo_sitemap translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Common)</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/template_container" name="seo.sitemap.container" template="catalog/seo/sitemap/container.phtml">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="seo.sitemap.links" as="links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Category List)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="catalog_seo_sitemap" />
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Categories</title></action>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_category" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.bottom</pager></action>
                <action method="setItemsTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>categories</title></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>Products Sitemap</label><url helper="catalog/map/getProductUrl"/><title>Products Sitemap</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category_tree translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Category Tree)</label>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" />
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" />
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_pager" name="seo.sitemap.tree.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_pager" name="seo.sitemap.tree.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" />
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_category" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap_tree" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/tree.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.tree.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.tree.pager.bottom</pager></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category_tree>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_product translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Product List)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="catalog_seo_sitemap" />
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Products</title></action>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_product" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.bottom</pager></action>
                <action method="setItemsTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>products</title></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>Categories Sitemap</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl"/><title>Categories Sitemap</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_product>
</layout>
```

It appears that these two lines in the above code are what handle the paging:

```
  <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
  <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

Can you please help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the file `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and add this line at the bottom of the file (or somewhere in there):

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```